# What am I doing wrong with this modulus?

Tags: c++

I wrote a c++ program that receives from user a number and Print 1 if positive and even, Print 2 if positive and odd, Print 3 if negative and even, Print 4 if negative and odd, Print 0 if zero.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n;
cin>>n;
if (n>0 && n%2==0)
    cout <<"1";
else if (n>0 && n%2==!0)
    cout <<"2";
else if (n<0 &&  n%2==0)
    cout <<"3";
else if (n<0 && n%2==!0)
    cout <<"4";
else if (n==0)
cout <<"0";
return 0;

}
```

Everything run pretty well except the 4th case whenever I enter negative and odd it prints nothing on the screen and that means nothing of all these cases are true, What am I doing wrong with the 4th, Isn't there a modulus to a negative number or what?

Comment: I assume you mean `!= 0` not `== !0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `n%2==!0` with `n % 2 != 0`. The extra spacing is my personal taste.

`n%2==!0` is evaluated as `n%2==(!0)` due to *operator precedence*, and `!0` is equal to `1`. Maddeningly, the way you have it works perfectly for the positive `n` case, but it breaks the negative `n % 2` case which, for odd negative `n`, returns `-1` from C++11 onwards. (Prior to that the result was implementation defined.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator precedence, since no other grouping is well formed in any way. Did you perhaps mean associativity?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I could say "hardwired into the grammar of the language"; indeed operator precedence is a corollary of this, but then this is becoming too much of a mouthful for the scope of this answer. `!` does come before `==` in the precedence table, so I best leave it as it is. However you could spruce up your answer. I was waiting with my +1 comment!

Comment: Nah. I wasn't gonna attack that angle. And while diversity in answers is good, I see no point in repeating yours verbatim :) When others speak for us, we vote!

Comment: And seeing as I still haven't figured out the short comment business, depriving you of the chance is oddly satisfying :P

Comment: @StoryTeller: Is !0 means factorial of 0?

Comment: @SarahAhmed - No, it's logical negation. A falsy value to a truthy value. That sort of thing. Also note `!` appears before the value it operates on, not after. There is no operator for a factorial in C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller `n%(2==!0)` would be another grouping